# Group (co)homology and classyfing spaces

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces

I would like to ask where I can find in the literature the *proof* of the following fact: the group cohomology of the group $G$ is naturally isomorphic with the ordinary (say singular) cohomology of the classyfing space $BG$ of $G$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is explained in Chater 8 of Weibel's "Introduction to Homological Algebra", specifically Example 8.2.3.

The idea is to revise the construction of $BG$ as the geometric realization of a certain simplicial set — the nerve $N G$ of $G$ viewed as a category:
$$BG = |NG|.$$
For any simplicial set $X$ its simplicial homology coincides with the cellular (and hence singular) homology of its geometric realization:
$$H_\bullet^\text{Simpl.} (X;\mathbb{Z}) \cong H_\bullet^\text{Sing.} (|X|;\mathbb{Z}).$$
On the other hand, the complex for calculating the simplicial homology of $NG$ coincides with the standard complex for calculating group homology (the one that comes from the bar-resolution), hence
$$H_\bullet (G,\mathbb{Z}) \cong H_\bullet^\text{Simpl.} (NG; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_\bullet^\text{Sing.} (BG; \mathbb{Z}).$$

---

Another reference: Section I.6 in Brown's ["Cohomology of Groups"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-9327-6) (GTM 87). This is more or less the same argument. The author checks that $C_\bullet (EG)$ is a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules, which coincides with the standard bar-resolution. It only remains to note that if you take the complex of fixed points $C_\bullet (EG)_G$, then you calculate both the group homology $H_\bullet (G,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_\bullet (BG;\mathbb{Z})$.

---

Actually, this is the right way to see where the bar-resolution comes from.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you just explain why we can realise $BG$ as the geometric realisation of the simplicial set being the nerve of the category $G$? I know different construction, as a quotient of $EG$ where $EG$ is obtained via infinite join construction by Milnor.

Comment: @truebaran See, for example, section 1.B in Hatcher's book: https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf He describes $EG$ and then $EG/G$; the result is precisely $|NG|$. You can also work out the homotopy groups of $|NG|$ — see Example 8.3.3 in Weibel's book.